# how to change the string array to string not use loop clause? Can it be implement by LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

> input:

```
  var pList=new []{"a","b","c"};
```

> output:

```
 string pListRet="a,b,c";
```

I know it can be implement in `JS` quickly like `pList.Join(",");`
But can it be implemented in C#?

Comment: "But can it be implemented in C#?" Oh trust me, it can always be implemented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You don't need Linq for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

```
var pList=new []{"a","b","c"};
string pListRet = String.Join(",",pList)
```

If you really really really want to use linq, this works:

```
var pList=new []{"a","b","c"}; 

string pListRet = pList.Aggregate((t,s) => t+(t==""?"":",")+s);
```

Comment: Gah!  You beat me on both approaches.  I actually had `string pListRet = pList.Skip(1).Aggregate(pList.First(), (accumulated, value) => accumulated + "," + value);` for the LINQ approach, although that throws an Exception if `pList` is empty.

Comment: @BACON Hm I actually like that better. Inline if expressions feel so dirty, yours is nice and clear.